# How To Use TouchEvent's in Subview Of UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, touch-event

I'm trying to catch touch events inside UIScrollView. Example : I have UIImageView inside UIScrollView. I'm using UIScrollViewDelegate to detect UIScrollView zoom actions. But when I try to get UIImageView touch events as touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded I can't get them. How can I get them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of `UIImageView` use `UIControl`, where the image can be assigned as

> controlView.layer.contents = image.cgImage

2. Place `UIImageView` inside `UIControl`, and for `UIImageView` set `isUnteractionEnabled` to `false`.

In both ways you can use `addTarget` to process `UIControl` clicks. There are also touch events like `beginTracking`, `continueTracking`. See more https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol

3. Use UITapGestureRecongizer:

> ```
> imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(
>            target: self, action: #selector(onImageViewTap(_:))))
>
> @objc func onImageViewTap(_ gr: UIGestureRecognizer) {
>     .....
> }
> ```